# jquery-lang-js translate with placeholders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Based of [this documentation](https://github.com/Irrelon/jquery-lang-js) jquery-lang-js supports placeholders for translations. 
My javascript and html implementation is like this:

```js
function changeLangOnClick(lang) {
      console.log('clicked language change');
      window.lang.change(lang);
      console.log(lang);
      Cookies.set('site_lang', lang, { expires: 7 });
      return false;
       }
    var lang = new Lang();
    var shownLang = Cookies.get('site_lang');
    console.log(lang);
    console.log('gets here');
 lang.dynamic('de', 'i18n/de.json');
 lang.dynamic('it', 'i18n/it.json');
    lang.dynamic('en', 'i18n/en.json');
        
        if (typeof shownLang === 'undefined') {
            shownLang = window.navigator.language;
        }
         if(shownLang =="en-US" && (shownLang!="de" || shownLang!="it")){
            shownLang="en";
        }
        
  lang.init({
   defaultLang: 'de',
            currentLang: shownLang
   
  });
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="language-select" onchange="changeLangOnClick(value);">
          <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
          <option value="it">Italiano</option>
          <option value="en">English</option>
</select>

<h2 lang="de" placeholder="placeholder1"></h2>
```

And I have this i18n/de.json like this:

```
{
"placeholder1": "WILLKOMMEN"
```

}

But when I switch to de lang I will get:

> jquery-lang.js:545 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'placeholder1' of undefined
>       at Lang.translate (http://localhost/curtiforti2/js/lang/jquery-lang.js:545:40)
>       at Lang._translateAttribs (http://localhost/curtiforti2/js/lang/jquery-lang.js:362:26)
>       at Lang._translateElement (http://localhost/curtiforti2/js/lang/jquery-lang.js:520:8)
>       at Lang.change (http://localhost/curtiforti2/js/lang/jquery-lang.js:494:11)
>       at http://localhost/curtiforti2/js/lang/jquery-lang.js:460:20
>       at Object.success (http://localhost/curtiforti2/js/lang/jquery-lang.js:175:22)
>       at i (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:27603)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:28369)
>       at A (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:4:13858)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:4:16146)

I have to add that on my console.logs for testing I get the correct language selected: console.log(lang);, and also checking cookies seem to save the correct language. My problem is only that **'placeholder1' of undefined**.

Comment: Can you edit your code so it's actually executable? =)

Comment: Please post a working example reproducing your problem, here's a start https://jsfiddle.net/m30u25ry/